# PhpStorm what is this background color?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

I really don't know how I did this, but now my code is highlighted with this ugly olive color and I get a warning: "No data sources are configured to run this SQL" but my files are all PHP without any SQL command.

Here is a screenshot below.

Please can anybody tell me how can I remove the ugly olive green/ light brown background color in the code highlighting.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post screenshots of your `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: i have edited the question and added 2 screenshots from the settings->Editor->Language Injections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Language Injections`
3. Delete 3rd rule from the bottom where it has `IDE` in the Scope column.

You have accidentally injected SQL language into `<div>` tag content... so everything inside such tag is treated as SQL.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. Now all is fine again.